# log4j2.properties tuning to set a specific log level for Spark only

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, log4j2

I'm updating my work project's log4j to log4j2 and am trying to grasp some syntax that has changed between the two API's.

I've pulled an example log4j2.properties from their site, below. Since Spark is super noisy at the INFO level, all I need to to is set the console appender to filter logs below WARN from 'org.apache.spark'. In the old API this was simply `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN`, but now it doesn't seem to be that simple.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = target/rolling/rollingtest.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = info

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = com.workplace.project
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: Were you able to sort this out ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below lines in your configuration file -

```
logger.org.apache.spark.name = org.apache.spark
logger.org.apache.spark.level = warn
logger.org.apache.spark.additivity = false
logger.org.apache.spark.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
logger.org.apache.spark.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: It still not setting the logs level for me , i am trying to set the eclipselink persistence package level to FINE or in log4j terms it is as DEBUG but this did not work out. Package name is org.eclipse.persistence.

Comment: @rinilnath you want to set more low level log level. In that case, in addition to above changes, you should change log level of your appender as well like `appender.console.filter.threshold.level=DEBUG`